# Use of Target in Picasso on Adapter

Tags: android, listview, picasso

Im having big troubles using a Target inside an adapter. Im confused about the documentation on the code

> Objects implementing this class **must** have a working implementation of
>     {@link #equals(Object)} and {@link #hashCode()} for proper storage internally. Instances of this
>     interface will also be compared to determine if view recycling is occurring. It is recommended
>     that you add this interface directly on to a custom view type when using in an adapter to ensure
>     correct recycling behavior.

Im trying to use the Target in this way:

```
class CustomTarget implements Target {
    private ImageView imageView;

    public CustomTarget(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(new RoundedAvatarDrawable(bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return imageView.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return imageView.hashCode();
    }
}

 @Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
....
    RoundedAvatarDrawable r = new RoundedAvatarDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_avatar_seahorse));
    ImageCacheController.with(mContext).getPicasso().load(member.getPicture_url()).resize(100, 100).centerCrop().placeholder(r).error(r).into(new CustomTarget(viewHolder.ivAvatar));
....
}
```

It's doesn't work and the images change between each others randomly

Comment: It seems your `getView()` is broken. Post your `getView()` method here. If you must, why not ask Eclipse to generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` method for you. **Right click > Source > Generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` ...**

Comment: And BTW Picasso also accepts `ImageView` so you don't need to write this wrapper class. Just send `ImageView` in `into()` method.

Comment: I'm using Target because I need a drawable wrapper named "RoundedAvatarDrawable" -> imageView.setImageDrawable(new RoundedAvatarDrawable(bitmap)); . That is for round the image as a circle.

Comment: Why you are not posting your `getView()`? Strip it and post the code please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't show your whole `getView` function, so without knowing how you use the viewHandler, here's my take on what's going on:

Your problem is that you're creating a new `CustomTarget` every time `getView` gets called. You are going against the point of having a `Target` object. Let me elaborate.

When a new download request is made, previous requests to the same target get stopped or don't result in a call to the Target's callbacks. (so if the Target gets reused for a different row in a list it doesn't get both rows' images).

You are using a new object for each request, effectively hinting Picasso that each request is for a different row so to speak. The doc says "*Instances of this interface will also be compared to determine if view recycling is occurring*", so since each request has a newly created `CustomTarget` object, no two requests will have the same object and a row recycle won't be detected.

You're also using viewHolder. In this case I think the viewHolder should be extending the `Target` interface (if you only have 1 image per row). This way everytime you request a download you can use the same object and not create a new one.

You're also delegating the implementation of your `CustomTarget` to the `ImageView`'s implementation. Make sure that ImageView's `equals` and `hashCode` functions fullfill the requirements Picasso asks for.

Some info on how to implement `equals` and `hashCode`: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: `ImageView`'s implementations will be fine.

Comment: @Jake Is the recycle check also done with those two functions? If so, then I think the issue is prob. not due to his use of equals and hashCode and my answer is mostly irrelevant. Or is the check looking for the same exact object (using ==)?

Comment: It is used by `WeakHashMap` which will use both methods for bucketing and then equality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your equals method is broken. You are comparing an imageview to a custom target. This might fix it:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof CustomTarget) {
        return ((CustomTarget) o).imageView.equals(this.imageView);
    }
    return super.equals(o);
}
```